# Firefox instances are not opening more than 5 instances inside container in docker

Tags: docker, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

Firefox instances are not opening more than 5 instances inside container in docker though we have provided node instances and session instance are more.

We have used below command to create firefox node debug setup

docker run -d -p 5903:5900 --link  selenium-hub:hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm  -e NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=15 -e NODE_MAX_SESSION=15 selenium/node-firefox-debug:3.141.59-20200409

Please let me know what might be the issue here.

Comment: To open firefox instance I have used below code 

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
      capabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore");
      //capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.fromString(os.toUpperCase()));
      capabilities.setCapability("maxDuration", 3600);
      driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, capabilities);